# How to simulate enter key pressed BUT ONLY press it after some seconds?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

If I want to simulate an enter key pressed,I just use:

```
echo -ne '\n' | mycommand
```

But "mycommand" requires to wait some seconds before actually press enter key.
How could I wait some seconds before simulate the enter key pressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(sleep 12; echo) | mycommand
```

`mycommand` will read an empty line after 12 seconds and see end-of-file straight after. If that's a problem, you can add a delay after as well:

```
(sleep 12; echo; sleep 5) | mycommand
```

See also `expect` to send input based on what the command outputs (it also uses pseudo-terminals which makes it look like there's a real user).

Comment: it works. but why `mycommand` executes before the end of commands in `()`?

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm in a pipeline, all parts are started at the same time and run concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

Use `expect`, something like this should do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn "mycommand"
expect "Press Enter to continue" { send "\r" }
interact
```

Of course, you need to change "Press Enter to continue" to the actual message.

Comment: Instead of `echo...` with flags, which acts differently depending on shell, consider using the more well-defined `printf "\n"` (or plain `echo` I suppose)

Comment: Or `echo` alone which sends a newline by itself already. Feels silly to remove that newline with `-n` (non-standard) just to add it back with `-e` (even less portable) and `\n`.

Comment: I just took that from the Q. But as you already have the more or less the same answer i switched to an `expect` solution ;-)

Comment: You may want to do `send "\r"` instead of `send "\n"` to similar pressing Return (shouldn't make much difference as the pty line discipline will likely translate `\r` to `\n` anyway)

Comment: (see also `spawn -noecho` to avoid echoing the command. Maybe `#! /usr/bin/env expect` as not many systems have `expect` in `/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use xdotool to simulate a "enter":

```
 xdotool key 'Return' | commandhere
```

or you can make it sleep then enter a command:

```
sleep 0.5; xdotool key 'Return' | commandhere
```

Comment: I think the intention was that the target program would start running, but it would then receive {Enter} after a few moments. A bit like [this other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598831/100397)

Comment: @roaima that works with this script       sleep 0.5; xdotool key 'Return' | curl https://repo.jellyfin.org/install-debuntu.sh | sudo bash in this example the script installs jellyfin and presses enter when prompted

Comment: Not really. It sends the Enter key immediately but the script downloaded from `curl` only looks for it after a few moments. That's different to the requirement